# Bootstrap dropdown menu links not clickable

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a page: http://www.poh.me/nordisk/ where the dropdown menu links on this page works, but the subslinks (e.g. http://www.poh.me/nordisk/contact/) the anchors becomes unclickable.

I've tried every thing from removing data-toggle from the links to z-index css and other tips I read from others having a similar problem.

Any help is much appreaciated :-)

Thanks!!

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have errors in your code:

[image]

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`

```
$(".links a, .nav a").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var dest = 0;

    //                Error here 
    //                       vvvv
    if ($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        dest = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
    } else {
        dest = $(this.hash).offset().top;
    }
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: dest}, 800, 'swing');
});
```

Comment: that's a nice, "in your face" answer :)