# Bootstrap 5 - Dropdown menu - Can't interract with links

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

as often, I wan't to add a Bootstrap 5 dropdown menu in my project but I got something unexpected.

The menu open correctly but when I try to hover my mouse on element's menu, the hover is not triggered and if I click on a link, nothing happens. It seems like my menu is placed behind any other element.

Here a: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Skunka/egxd0cz3/)

Code Html:

```
<body>
<div id="side-bar">

</div>

<div id="top-bar">


  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between top-bar-content">
    <div>
      <nav style="--bs-breadcrumb-divider: '>';" aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
          <li class="breadcrumb-item active">
            <a href="/accueil">Accueil</a>
          </li>
        </ol>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div>
      <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
      <span class="text-white mx-2">Username</span>
      <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" id="dropdown_user">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown_user">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/utilisateur/1">Mon profil</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/utilisateur/">Administration</a></li>
        <li>
          <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
        </li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout">Me déconnecter</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>


<div id="main-content">
  Suuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuper 
  loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text
  
  <div>
    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
    <span class="text-white mx-2">Username</span>
    <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" id="dropdown_user">
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown_user">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/utilisateur/1">Mon profil</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/utilisateur/">Administration</a></li>
      <li>
        <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
      </li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout">Me déconnecter</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Code Sass:

```
body
    background-color: ghostwithe
    min-height: 100%

a
    text-decoration: none !important
    color: inherit !important

$breadcrumb-divider-color: black
$breadcrumb-active-color: black

.bold
    font-weight: bold

#side-bar
    position: fixed
    width: 260px
    z-index: 1000
    left: 0
    top: 0
    border-right: 1px solid #162636
    min-height: 100vh
    border-right: 3px solid grey

#top-bar
    position: fixed
    top: 0
    right: 0
    width: calc( 100vw - 260px )
    height: 50px
    background-color: #0984e3

#main-content
    position: fixed
    right: 0
    width: calc( 100vw - 260px )
    height: calc( 100vh - 50px )
    margin-top: 50px
    padding-left: 5px
    padding-right: 5px
    overflow-y: auto
    overflow-x: hidden

hr
    margin: 2px auto 2px auto
    border: none
    height: 2px !important

hr.cyan
    color: cyan

hr.grey
    color: #162636

.top-bar-content
    margin: 13px

.breadcrumb
    margin-bottom: 0 !important
    color: black

.breadcrumb-item
    &.active
        color: white
    &:hover
        color: white !important
```

But if I place my dropdown menu somewhere else, it work correctly (like in #main-content div [see in jsfiddle]).

I looked around the web but it's seems like they're isn't any similar question to my problem.

Here some of similar case which didn't give me a usefull answer in my case:

- [Bootstrap link not clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352611/bootstrap-dropdown-menu-links-not-clickable)
- [Bootstrap 4 navbar dropdown menu item not clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38510524/bootstrap-4-navbar-dropdown-menu-item-not-clickable-on-mobile-devices)

They're isn't error message.

I wan't to be able to interract with my dropdown menu.

In hope someone have a solution, I'm free to give you more informations.

Thanks !

Edit: just under $breadcrumb-active-color, they're is normally

> @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"

that I removed from JsFiddle because I think it was in conflict with JsFiddle bootstrap importation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the #top-bar and #main-content are fixed and hence #main-content is stacked over #top-bar. So when you are clicking the submenu it is overflowing into the #main-content but it is under it. Add `z-index` to #top-bar something higher than that of #main-content, which is > 1 but preferably 9.

Comment: I already added z-index but I added it to dropdown menu instead of #top-content. 
This work as expected, thank you !